# jQuery - unbind and bind again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi I tried to show the div (blue one) on mouseenter but only then, when ul has class hidden.

I have done it but how i dont know how can i bind again function which will show the blue div on mouseenter ..
To test it hover on the white li, then click the violet button and try to hover white li again - in the last step should show blue li but ii wont :(

this is my fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nduU7/17/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e){


$('li').each( function() { 
    var elem_number = $(this).index();
         $(this).html(elem_number + 1);
});

$('.left-panel-toggle').on('click', function () {    
    if($('ul').hasClass('hidden')) {
      $('ul').animate({width:'150px'}, 200).addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
        $('li').animate({height:'100px',width:'150px'}, 200); 
  $('li').unbind("mouseenter");

} else {
  $('ul').animate({width:'35px'}, 200).addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
    $('li').animate({height:'30px', width:'30px'}, 200);
    }
});


$( "li" ).bind('mouseenter',function(e) {
      if($('ul').attr('class') == 'hidden') {
          $('.tooltip').show().animate({'left':'36px','opacity':'1'},100);
                var tooltip_height = $('.tooltip').height();
                var tooltip_width = $('.tooltip').width();
                var  viewHeightY = $(window).height(); 

            var li_position = $(this).position();
            var li_height = $(this).height();
            var li_width = $(this).width();

            var tooltip_position = $('.tooltip').position();
            var tt = tooltip_position.top + tooltip_height

if(li_position.top < tooltip_height/2) {
      $('.tooltip').css({'top':li_position.top - li_position.top,                 'left':li_position.left + li_width + 15});            
}
if(li_position.top > tooltip_height/2) {
      $('.tooltip').css({'top':li_position.top - tooltip_height/2, 'left':li_position.left + li_width + 15});            
}
if((viewHeightY - li_position.top) < tooltip_height/2) {
     $('.tooltip').css({'top':li_position.top -((li_position.top +  tooltip_height)-viewHeightY), 'left':li_position.left + li_width + 15});            
    }
}
//    $('img.x').attr('src', $(this.img).val('src'));
e.preventDefault(); 
});

$( "ul" ).bind('mouseleave', function() {            
            $('.tooltip').animate({'left':'56px','opacity':'0'},60);
    });  
});
```

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nduU7/18/

Comment: yes :) but when the ul has class visible Blue div should not show.

Comment: i do not understand... you put condition: if ul has class visible, to not show blue div... then you add class visible to ul and you wonder why the blue div is not visible anymore ?!

Comment: i think now on another test case: first time show blue div.. then expand ul, do not show blue div on hover... then shrink again the ul and show again the blue div... this is what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/nduU7/19/

Comment: I hope you understood the modification: i deleted the unbind() . Because you already had an IF in the mouseenter event, that worked perfectly. No need to unbind mouseenter . Just check inside it if you want to show or not the blue div. The event is there all the time